# Heading off to college - need help engineering a way around campus ethernet restrictions

Tags: routing, switch

[image]
This is all a bit outside my area of expertise, and to be honest, i'm not even sure its possible.

My roomate and I both have raspberry pis scraping data in fixed intervals that need to operate over ethernet to minimize latency. Our university prohibits the usage of ethernet switches. There are only two ports in the room and we need about 5 devices connected. I lack the knowledge to give you the proper names of the devices I hope to find but I'm envisioning a router or switch-like device that can do the following:

1. Allow for LAN communication between our computers, the raspberry pis scraping data, and the Jetson Nano which processes that data.
2. Allow both of our PCs to access a print server run on a raspberry pi
3. Hide all of these devices behind a facade that can represent the internet connection needs of all these devices as one single connection while hiding all our devices behind it
4. configurable enough to where we could modify the properties of the device to make it appear as just a simple desktop computer or something else, so as to not raise suspicion by the IT department.

Is this a real device, or is there a way that I can do this with multiple devices?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Networks not under your control and especially working around network security in another's network are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Network engineers are not willing to explain to you how to hack their own networks, which is why questions about bypassing network security or policies are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that makes sense, was not aware of that principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't violate your university's I.T. policies.  The best plan would be to discuss your needs with an on-campus computer club and see if they can help you find a way to do what you want in a supported manner.  For example, my university's main computer club had a lounge/office/lab which was used to host many student projects, small web servers, etc.

With that said, if you do get permission to hook all this up, you may need to use a router with NAT and 802.1X or captive portal supplicant support.  These are actually pretty common features for *prosumer routers* such as the more-expensive ASUS and Netgear Nighthawk series.

You might need to click through / login via a captive portal on a PC and then clone that PC's MAC address using the router.  Again, this is a common configuration for prosumer routers.

The above features basically do what you want, and make all the downstream devices appear to be an ordinary PC, for the most part.

Good luck with your projects.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your very understanding response. I will be going to a fairly large university with a nationally strong computer science program and I'm sure they could help me with these; I'm not sure why the thought never crosses my find. thank you for the reality check!